# Change XIB background colour in Interface Builder

Tags: iphone, xcode

I'm trying to change the background colour of a View in Interface Builder.

I can change text in this View but when I go to Attributes > View > Background and select a different colour it refuses to show it in the Simulator. Instead I just get a dark gray background.

Is this another bug in Xcode 4?

Answer (score 0):

Hmm - no Xcode bug.

It was down to a rather annoying line of auto-generated code in the FlipSide View controller which overrode the Interface Builder settings.

```
self.view.backgroundColor = [UIColor viewFlipsideBackgroundColor];
```